# JS - Set Div Height To Window Height

Tags: javascript, window, height

In my little file below I want to have it where if the red div height is greater than the window height that the blue div height will be 0. If the red div height is less then the window height the blue div height will set its height where the blue and red divs will fit in the window.

This code below does work in firefox but does not work in chrome or ie/edge. This is my struggle, making it work across all the browsers.

```
<style>

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#red {
    height: 200px;

    background-color: red;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

</style>

<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>

<script>

document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[1].style.height = (window.innerHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) + 'px';

</script>
```

Comment: You could consider a CSS solution to this problem. Based on your condition, you can set `min/max-height` and/or use flexbox to accomplish this.

Comment: From your description, are you trying to create a responsive element with a minimum height? Generally if you can avoid setting styles from JS, it's more effective to just add/remove classes if needed.